# How to avoid creating so many dtos when facing SOA migration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, soa, dto

We are now doing SOA migration and our old system's architecture is based on spring and hibernate. We use PO (persistence object) across all the layers.

When facing SOA migration, if we use DTO for remote procedure call, we have to create so many DTOs.

What are some suggestions on how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Develop a [Canonical Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Model), probably the most important SOA pattern there is.
 - Define a representation using an XML Schema for that model.
 - Use [jaxb](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) to [create](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) the Java POJO representations.
Once you have these you 'could' map these to your existing Persistent Objects and then round-trip until they are equivalent.
Alternatively given you already use persistent object you could work bottom up with Jaxb, but in my experience that is more difficult/work intensive approach.